# Excel: Check if a value is in another column and if yes attribute another value

Tags: excel, cell

Excel: I want to check if a given value (cell `A2`) is in another column (to check in all column B). Column B has values associated in column C. If `A2` is in column B, I want the correspondent value in column C to be zero. If not, I want to keep the original value in column C. (Column A has other values that I want to search in column B).

How do I do this?

Comment: With vba or in another column.  You can have a formula or you can have a value in a cell but not both.  If you want a formula you will need to have a column with the values that you want to put in C when there is no match

Comment: So which formula do I have to apply (in another column) if I only want to know if A2 (and all other values in A) are present in column B? And for return get something like "true"/"false"

Comment: In a separate column in the second row put `=ISNUMBER(MATCH(A2,B:B,0))` Then copy down.  It will Return True for those that have a match and False for those who do not.

Comment: It works, thank you very much!!!!

Answer (score 2):

This will find the **first instance** of the value in cell **A2** in column **B**.  Once found, zero is placed in column **C** adjacent to the found cell:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim r As Range
    Dim B As Range

    Set B = Range("B:B")
    Set r = B.Find(What:=Range("A2").Value, After:=B(1))
    If r Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    r.Offset(0, 1) = 0
End Sub
```